# How to get WAMP immediately loging into error_log?

Tags: php, windows, apache, wamp, error-log

Error log in wamp is on, running, but changes can be seen there after 1-30minutes. It's not problem like [Why won't Apache 2.1.7 in WAMP log PHP errors to the PHP error log?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5095784/apache-2-1-7-in-wamp-wont-log-php-errors-to-php-error-log) - with generally logging, but with flushing info to log from apache/php. I'm using windows 7, i don't remember this problem on XP.

Comment: which software are you using to read the log?

Comment: Tail for Win32. Behavior of access log is correct. Also in any directory viewer i don't see changes after writing to error_log...but after some time spontaneously is filled.

Comment: maybe the problem is with tail for windows not getting the correct file change.

Comment: Not: "Behavior of access log is correct. Also in any directory viewer i don't see changes after writing to error_log...but after some time spontaneously is filled." - program is indiferrent.

Comment: It's something with flushing error info on the file/disc in intervals.

Answer (score 0):

The line ; log_errors is commented

```
log_errors = Off
```

And change the value to On. You notepad to open the error log file. [Read more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5095784/apache-2-1-7-in-wamp-wont-log-php-errors-to-php-error-log)

Comment: Dusan not, this line is uncommented also ;-) It's not problem with logging, but with writing log info into file/disc. From any cache...